# Issue parsing json from case class using jackson

Tags: java, json, scala, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am attempting to use the aws lambda seed project received from **[here](https://github.com/yeghishe/scala-aws-lambda-seed.g8)**

The source code for the generated project is **[here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/aws-scala-start)**

I imported the sbt dependencies and built the project using **sbt assembly** command.

I took the jar file built and uploaded it to lambda directly. For the handler defined for at **MyHandler::handler**

```
// handler io.github.yeghishe.MySimpleHander::handler
// input "foo"
object MySimpleHander extends App {
  def handler(name: String, context: Context): String = s"Hello $name"
}

case class Name(val name: String)
case class Greeting(val message: String)

// handler io.github.yeghishe.MyHandler
// input {"name": "Yeghishe"}
class MyHandler extends Handler[Name, Greeting] {
  def handler(name: Name, context: Context): Greeting = {
    logger.info(s"Name is $name")
    Greeting(s"Hello ${name.name}")
  }
}
```

with the input event:

```
{
  "name": "Yeghishe"
}
```

When I call the function, it shows the error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred during JSON parsing",
  "errorType": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "stackTrace": [],
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.lendi.hellolambda.Name]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@1dfe2924; line: 1, column: 2]",
    "errorType": "java.io.UncheckedIOException",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "cause": {
      "errorMessage": "No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.lendi.hellolambda.Name]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@1dfe2924; line: 1, column: 2]",
      "errorType": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
      "stackTrace": [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1106)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:296)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) or any other Scala-aware configuration of Jackson? By default Jackson can't deserialize case classes. So show us your Jackson configuration.

Comment: The seed project [depends on a library that uses the circe library for parsing json from an input stream](https://github.com/yeghishe/scala-aws-lambda-utils/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/github/yeghishe/lambda/Handler.scala), it is based on this [blog post](http://yeghishe.github.io/2016/10/16/writing-aws-lambdas-in-scala.html) which makes it much stranger when we have the method issuing a Jackson error

Comment: Sorry but your stack trace obviously comes from Jackson rather than Circe. I'm not sure how exactly this happens. Are you sure you are running the code you show?

Comment: @SergGr I upload the code to lambda, I set the handler to `com.lendi.hellolambda.MyHandler::handler` and run the code in lambda

Comment: Maybe you should have set your handler to just `com.lendi.hellolambda.MyHandler` or `com.lendi.hellolambda.MyHandler::handleRequest` (which comes from the base `Handler`) See also [Example: Using Stream for Handler Input/Output (Java)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html)